# Rails: Filter index page and Re-display filter inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am not sure what the proper Rails 3 way to do this is. I want to have filter criteria fields at the top of my index view that will filter the data.

What I have below works for filtering my list, but I also want the filter fields to be re-populated with what the current filter is, and I can't figure out how to do that.  The method I got working below also doesn't feel like the "right" way to accomplish this, since it relies on things like passing empty string to the field helper methods in my view.

Controller:

```
 def index

@animals = Animal.by_color(params[':color']).by_age(params[':age']).paginate(:page => params[:page])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @animals }
end
```

end

View:

```
<h1>Listing Animals</h1>

Filter By:
<%= form_for(:animal, :url => { :action => "index" }, :html => {:method => :get} ) do |f| %>
<div>
  Color: <%= text_field'', ':color', :size => 10 ) %>
  Age: <%= text_field('', ':age') %>
  <%= f.submit "Filter List" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate %>

...
```

I am using the scope methods in my Model, which work very slick.  I am just fuzzy about how the Controller "params" method and the View methods "form_for", "text_field" map to each other. Any ideas on how to refactor this and also get my filter fields populated when the list is currently filtered?

### Solution!

Controller:

```
def index

@search = Animal.new(params[:animal])
@animals = Animal.by_color(@search.color)...

....
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@search, :url => { :action => "index" }, :html => {:method => :get} ) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field(:color)
```

The form population works by creating the @search object in my contorller (in addition to my main animals object). Then using form_for to create a for around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a "query by example", which would work roughly like this in controller:

```
@filter = Animal.new(params[:filter])
@animals = @filter.get_scope.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

and in the controller you could do a `form_for` on that example record, but I am not aware of any
modern Rails plugins that do exactly that. There certainly should be something like this though, look thoroughly. I bet you could write something similar in a couple of hours though (just grab the attributes hash of your filter record into the `:conditions` of the scope, rougly like so - NOT TESTED THOUGH):

```
 def get_scope
   # remove all nill attrs
   non_default_attrs = self.attributes
   self.columns.each do | col |
     # Ignore columns that have default values
     non_default_attrs.delete(col.name) if non_default_attrs[col.name] == column.default
     # Ignore columns whose values are nils
     non_default_attrs.delete(col.name) if non_default_attrs[col.name].nil?
   end

   where(non_default_attrs.symbolize_keys)
 end
```

Comment: The scoping is already working. I am using the Rails 3 scope methods in my Model like this:

`scope :by_co_color, lambda { |*args|
          unless args.first.blank?
            where("color like ?", args.first.concat('%'))
          end
        }
`

Comment: I am trying to figure out the Controller<->View interaction that will retain the contents of the filter text fields when they have been used to filter my index page.

Comment: Well that is the thing - your record would persist the params from the filter form through the request-response loop since the form would be rendered with it's data

Comment: I got it! I got distracted by your suggestion of a different scoping implementation, but you got me close to the solution. The key was creating a new Animal active record object and creating my form around that.

Here is what I ended up with:
Controller:
`@search = Animal.new(params[:animal])
@animals = Animal.by_color(@search.color)...`
View:
`<%= form_for(@search, :url => { :action => "index" }, :html => {:method => :get} ) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field(:color) %>
`

Answer (score -1):

controller

```
@search = params[:animal]
@animals = Animal.by_color(params[:color]).by_age(params[:age]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

views

```
<h1>Listing Animals</h1>

Filter By:
<%= form_tag animals_path do %>
<div>
  Color: <%= text_field_tag 'color', :size => 10 %>
  Age: <%= text_field_tag 'age' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filter List" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I'm looking for. It doesn't populate the search fields after the list hase been filtered. Doesn't even filter the list - which I already have working.

Comment: so you're doing something wrong, man. it should work as you want

Comment: The form_tag in your suggested code routes to the edit page, which is the default for a POST, which I fixed by adding `:method => 'get'`.  The text_field_tag example you give is missing a parameter for the value, and as written populates the text box with 'size10'.  Finally, params[:color] does not contain the value from the text field, so the filtering does not work. So even if I fix all those things, the filtered on value doesn't end up back in the text field after clicking the Filter List button. Sorry, I'm not trying to sound agrumentative.  I think I am still missing something.