# Rails user search and filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked into sphinx and watched the railscast tutorial on it, but I don't need full text search. I would like to be able to allow people to search for a user, either by name or email. And after someone searches for a user by name or email, they can further filter it by adding in the user's city.

I don't really think full text search is necessary for that. But I've never done any kind of searching in rails and I don't know how to do it without a gem.

I know it's kind of like User.where(:name=> ) based on my googling or something like that, but I'm not sure exactly how it is done or whether this is good for performance.

How could I implement what I want to do, and is a full text search necessary?

Comment: You are correct. A full text Search is not necessary for this.  A full text search would be useful if you wanted to search articles text for a certain word.  What you are going to be doing here is finding one or more users which are ActiveRecord objects, rows in a database.  Have you completed the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0#top)?

Comment: yes, I did. He had a little paragraph on search, and mentioned thinking sphinx and also linked to a railscast from 2007. I figured it was outdated.

Comment: I know there is a find by name and find my email method built into rails, but I'm not exactly sure how I would implement that into a search form and how to further filter it by city.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903339/rails-filter-index-page-and-re-display-filter-inputs) of what you are trying to do.  Over the weekend I might be able to implement something in a sample app to help you out more.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That would be great if you did. You Really don't have to, but that's really sweet. I've decided to learn development with Rails without prior programming experience, and I'm a politics major, so I never dealt with programming before but I'm picking up things quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two-column `WHERE`:

`User.where("name like ? or email like ?", "%steve%", "%gmail%")`

Scoped by city:

`User.where("name like ? or email like ?", "%steve%", "%gmail%").where("city like ?", "%vegas%")`

Note that the case-insensitive LIKE syntax is different from one database to another.  I use Postgres so I drop in an `ILIKE` for insensitive likes.

Comment: I am using Postgres. Would I have to add indices on the email, name, and city for performance? And how could I implement this into a universal search? Meaning, I have a fixed nav bar on every page with a search form. I know the form would be a get request and I could set the form to a specific controller and action (and point it to a search controller). So In the search controller would I have something like @search = User.search(params[:search]) by building your code into a search method in the User model, but how would I further filter it by search by adding a search box to the results page?